# how to redirect paypal after payment with values? PHP

Tags: php, api, redirect, paypal

I want that people will be able to insert x money into the database,
so what i need is how to redirect after payment with value,
by value i mean the number of the "money" that the user pay.
if someone pay 20 dollars so after the he pay with paypal he will be redirect to a page that will insert 20 dollars into the database
thanks you very much!
and sorry for my English :)

Comment: use paypals IPN , to insert the amount

Comment: Or set a `return` value in your form and make sure your paypal account have autoreturn set to enabled. Check paypal api docs.

Comment: even with the return you always use IPN for verifying the transaction and actual amount paid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be safe at all you must use paypal's IPN. This allows you to receive a callback from paypals servers to verify that payment actually went through. If you only use the redirect from paypal to verify that payment has been made, you will be a victim of fraud almost guaranteed.

Paypal IPN:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/